# MVC 3.0 newbie - how do I set display name?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

Consider this class used for DB mapping.

```
[Bind()]
public class ActiveType
{

    [Key()]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Navn")]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public string Suffix { get; set; }

}
```

As you can see, I tried to use the Display annotation to make MVC use that name when it auto-generates entity-framework CRUD pages. However, it ignores it. How do I change this? Is it possible through annotations?

Comment: That should work.  How are you displaying the name on the page?  Can you post the aspx or razor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example I provided actually worked, but not for auto-generated EF pages, where it would ignore it in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you are genarating your domain classes it will remove the attributes you have added.
It seems like you are using the domain object in entity framework layer for the model in MVC layer. This is not a good practice. You need to create separate view models (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/01/26/view-models-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) for the MVC layer. Because you need to separate the presentation logic from the data layer.
You can use something like AutoMapper to map domain object to view model. http://sourceforge.net/projects/automapper-dn/